Show that $\frac{(a+1)(a-b)}{b+1}+ \frac{(b+1)(b-c)}{c+1} + \frac{(c+1)(c-a)}{a+1} \geq 0$
The problem
Let $a,b$ be some real nonzero numbers. Show that:
a) $a^2 \geq \frac{b(a+1)^2}{b+1}-b$
b) $\frac{(a+1)(a-b)}{b+1}+ \frac{(b+1)(b-c)}{c+1} + \frac{(c+1)(c-a)}{a+1} \geq 0$
my idea
I was able to do a)
we  have to show that $a^2 \geq \frac{b(a+1)^2}{b+1}-b <=> a^2+b \geq \frac{b(a+1)^2}{b+1} <=> (a^2+b)(b+1) \geq b(a+1)^2 <=> a^2b+a^2+b^2+b \geq a^2b+2ab+b <=> a^2+b^2-2ab \geq 0 <=> (a-b)^2 \geq 0$ (TRUE) so we demonstrated the inequality
For point b) I thought of using what we demonstrated at a) but got to nothing useful
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

What if one of $a, b, c$ is $-1$? And note that multiplication with $(b+1)$ reverses the direction of the inequality if $b < -1$.

@MartinR But they cant be equal -1 because the denominator cant be equal to 0. Correct me if im wrong

It is the other way around: The inequality is not defined if a denominator is zero. So the problem description should state that $a, b, c \ne -1$.  – In any case, the first inequality is wrong if $b < -1$. Perhaps it should be “Let $a, b, c > -1$ be real numbers ...”?

It would also be interesting to know if the problems (a) and (b) are connected. Is it expected that solving (a) helps to solve (b)?

@MartinR Yes they are in the same exercise, so I think they are surely connected. This is why I wrote both of them...

The second inequality is wrong for $(a, b, c) = (-2, -3, -4)$.

It might be that the numbers are positive.

I'd agree with Martin. Assuming $a, b, c > -1$, I guess it's possible to show the result.

I checked the problem it says any real numbers...it might be a mistake in the problem tho

The second inequality is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3768846/42969 . Set $(x, y, z) = (a+1, b+1, c+1)$.

@MartinR you should elaborate your comment in an answer

@Momo: IMO the question should either be closed as “Needs details or clarity” because the statement is obviously wrong for $a, b, c < -1$, or as a duplicate.

@MartinR I don't think that it is that much obvious that one inequality follows from the other unless it is told beforehand.
